# Use Jquery to access nested HTML tags

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to access an id that is nested, but is also duplicated in a number of areas. Something similar to the following sample markup:

```
<td id='one'>
    <p id='up'>up 1</p>
    <p id='down'>down 1</p>
</td>
<td id='two'>
    <p id='up'>up 2</p>
    <p id='down'>down 2</p>
</td>
```

I tried using

```
$('#three').click(function(){
    $('td#one p#up').hide();
});
```

but that doesn't work. But this does work:

```
$('#four').click(function(){
    $('p#up').hide();
});
```

Can someone explain how to hide specifically the p tag with the text 'up 1'?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6UBwD/

All help is appreciated

EDIT: Changed id's to classes, and still no dice. What am I doing wrong? FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/6UBwD/4/

Comment: You shouldn't have duplicate ids, change them to classes.

Comment: See my answer for why the jsfiddle still doesn't work http://stackoverflow.com/a/24874901/3371119

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is that you shouldn't have `<td>` elements inside `<ul>`. [See this for more information](http://jsfiddle.net/7vc8R/1).

[This will work](http://jsfiddle.net/6UBwD/2/)

I replaced `td` with `div`

```
<ul>
    <div id='one'>
        <p id='up'>up 1</p>
        <p id='down'>down 1</p>
    </div>
    <div id='two'>
        <p id='up'>up 2</p>
        <p id='down'>down 2</p>
    </div>
        <div>
        <button id='three'>click here - doesnt work</button>
    </div>
        <div>
        <button id='four'>click here -- works</button>
    </div>
</ul>
```

However, as other's have pointed out, this works but isn't reliable. You cannot have multiple elements with the same `id` in the same document. You should use `class` instead of `id`. You can then do

```
$('#three').click(function(){
    $('#one p.up').hide();
});

$('#four').click(function(){
    $('p.up').hide();
});
```

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <div id='one'>
        <p class='up'>up 1</p> <!-- Notice class="up" instead of id="up" -->
        <!-- Alternatively, you could do "up1", "up2", so on as ids -->
        <p class='down'>down 1</p>
    </div>
    <div id='two'>
        <p class='up'>up 2</p>
        <p class='down'>down 2</p>
    </div>
        <div>
        <button id='three'>click here - doesnt work</button>
    </div>
        <div>
        <button id='four'>click here -- works</button>
    </div>
</ul>
```

[Working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/55fgy/1/)

Answer (score 1):

ID should be an unique within the HTML document. Use class instead. See this: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp

Answer (score 1):

First of all, this is not valid html, [according to the HTML 5 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#the-id-attribute) which says ID must be unique within a document.

To answer your question, you can create "nested" JQuery selectors by separating them with a simple space ie `jQuery('#mySelectorId1 #mySelectorId2')`.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments you shouldn't have duplicate ids.

One option is to give each `<p>` a unique id and hide the specific one that you want to hide

```
$('#three').click(function(){
    $('#up1').hide();
});
```

### [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Lu2R4/2/)

Comment: Is it possible to reuse classes rather than use unique id's? My actual html file is somewhat complicated but is set up in a similar fashion to the sample code above. Could you check out my edit please?

Comment: look at @soktinpk answer, i think he's got the answer if you want to keep classes